# Check if any tags have a certain inner HTML

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, iterator

How would i write a jquery function that returns true if any spans within a div with id 'word' have an inner HTML of value v? For the selector, I have:

```
$('#word span').html()
```

I'm confused as to the correct way to iterate through them, and return a boolean value because currently i have 5 span tags within that div.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use `:contains` as in `$("#word span:contains(v)")`, but that selects spans that *contain* 'v' rather than have it as an exact value.  `.html` only returns the html string of the *first* element selected, so you probably want to iterate with `.each` and do an exact comparison:

```
var count = 0;
$("#word span").each(function () {
   if ($.trim($(this).text()) === 'v') {
      count++;
   }
});
```

Comment: Maybe a combination whereby `contains` is used first? That way you only cache potential matches and then iterate only through a focused set of spans rather than caching and iterating through all spans all the time. I'm not worried about performance at all, I'm only looking at it from a logical perspective when reading the code.

Comment: This is a good alternative to contains, makes me wonder how efficient contains is, since it must do something very similar, internally. I'm going to look into the source code.

Answer (score 2):

## The `contains` selector

Since you are alread using jQuery, you can take advantage of its `.contains` method or the ':contains' pseudo-selector:

```
$("#word span").contains("word")
```

*OR*

```
$("#word span:contains(word)")
```

This would not return true for each span that contains the word, but rather the elements that contain that word. You would be left with a list of matched elements, that can be manipulated like so:

```
var $matched = $("word span").contains("word");

$matched.each(function (i, el) {
    // do something with the el
});
```

## Reference

http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.contains/

Answer (score 2):

You can use `filter` method:

```
$("#word span").filter(function () {
      return this.innerHTML === v; // in case that v is a variable
      // return $(this).text() === 'v';  
}).length;
```

Comment: Is it better to add a `':contains(' + v + ')'` to the selector and filter out all the silly nodes with spaces or newlines? Then the `filter()` only gets applied to text nodes that could exactly equal the text. I've never actually compared them for speed.

Comment: @LeeMeador Well `contains` selector selects the elements that _contain_ specific value, not necessary those that that their   content equal to that value(+ _hidden characters_), it selects `\n v`,  `v something`, `v `, it differs from an exact match, so removing the whitespace and other hidden characters is not an option here, in those cases using `filter` and `$.trim` is the best option.